# Easiest way to get max rank in Excel for all US States by Month?

Tags: excel, parsing, pivot-table, spreadsheet, data-cleaning

I'm working on a visualization project at work - it will display which of our partners sells the highest amount of merchandise per month from Jan to Dec last year. Currently, our company's business intelligence tool outputs the following

```
Ship State     Month        Partner        Net Demand
   AK            Jan       Coca-Cola          3200
   AK            Jan       Wegman's           2800
   AK            Jan       Target             2000
   ...
   AL            Jan       Coca-Cola          2600
   AL            Jan       Walmart            2100
   AL            Jan       Target              700
   ...
   WY            Jan       Wegmans            1600
   WY            Jan       Cola               200
   WY            Jan       Target             98
  ...
   AK            Feb       Coca-Cola          3100
   AK            Feb       Wegman's           2700
   AK            Feb       Target             1600
 ...
```

And so on. This is the current output - below is my desired output...

```
Ship State     Month        Partner        Net Demand
   AK            Jan       Coca-Cola          3200
   AL            Jan       Coca-Cola          2600
 ...  
   WY            Jan       Wegmans            1600
  ...
   AK            Feb       Coca-Cola          3100
 ...
```

If this makes sense. I only want the first ranked partner by top net demand. I don't want all of the others outputting. My company's BI tool is very limited. I've tried a pivot table in Excel, which gets me the ranks in a pivot table format, but when I copy/paste, the values all output wrongly. I filter by month and then state, so it's a vertical breakdown, I can't get all the values next to each other to feed into R. When I copy/paste, it looks like...

```
Jan 
AK 
Coca Cola     3200 
AL 
Coca Cola     2600
... etc
```

Is there any way to efficiently output and organize this? I need to do each partner for each state and intensive cleanup would take a lot of time because we have a lot of partners I'd have to delete and what not. I just want to output max rank per state per month - which is all the US states over a 12 month period.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished using Power Query, available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Excel 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range` or `from within sheet`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//Change next line to return your actual table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

//set data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Ship State", type text}, {"Month", type text}, {"Partner", type text}, {"Net Demand", Int64.Type}}),

//Remove rows containing "..."
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Ship State] <> "...")),

//group by State and Month
//then filter each subtable for the maximum Net Demand
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Ship State", "Month"}, {
        {"All", (t)=> Table.SelectRows(t, each [Net Demand] = List.Max(t[Net Demand])), 
        type table [Ship State=nullable text, Month=nullable text, Partner=nullable text, Net Demand=nullable number]}}),

//Re-exand the relevant table columns
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Partner", "Net Demand"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

[image]